# How to handle a # and multiple tns: in XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an excel sheet that has 106 columns and thousands of rows. It comes from an XML table that no longer exist. I would like to rebuild it and be able to handle data again with the XML.

However, I am a bit unaware about how to build the XML schema.

I have tried to use the headers as elements as is (doesn't work) and I have tried to write different headers and that wont work.

This is my table in excel, Column A to F. I'm not sure how to recreate the table here on StackOverflow.

```
/tns:Faktura/@typ   /tns:Faktura/tns:P_1    /tns:Faktura/tns:P_106E_2   /tns:Faktura/tns:P_106E_3   /tns:Faktura/tns:P_13_1 /tns:Faktura/tns:P_13_1/#agg
G   2018-07-04  false   false   380     380
G   2018-07-04  false   false   1500    1500
G   2018-07-12  false   false   120     120
G   2018-07-18  false   false   579     579
G   2018-07-18  false   false   205     205
G   2018-07-18  false   false   210     210
```

I tried to create a schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<JPK_FAS_SALES_INVOICES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Faktura>   
    <Faktura typ="G">G</Faktura>
    <P_1>43285</P_1>
    <P_106E_2>false</P_106E_2>
    <P_106E_3>false</P_106E_3>
    <P_13_1>380</P_13_1>
    <P_13_1 id="agg">380</P_13_1>
</Faktura>
```

I would obviously have to create more rows, but I I don't know how to handle the @ and the #agg.

Should I just create a simple schema with 106 columns.

Comment: You do not need the schema.  Using VBA macros you could create the xml by just writing strings to a text file one line at a time.  I've don it before.

Comment: @jdweng would you be kind enough to show me or point me in a direction on how to do this? I am not familiar with this (I know a bit of VBA though)